# How to keep element with position: absolute on the same position when resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to keep element with position: absolute on the same position when resizing?

I would like to have the button inside my input, but the problem is when I am trying to use position relative on parent and absolute on children it is not working as I want.

Right now, the element is on the correct position when the width of the browser is 375px

Maybe there is a diffrent solution?

```
<main class="page-main">
      <h1 class="page-main__title">
        <span>We're</span>
        coming soon
      </h1>
      <p class="page-main__text">
        Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store. Add your
        email below to stay up-to-date with announcemenets and our launch deals.
      </p>
      <form class="page-main__form">
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input
          type="email"
          class="page-main__input"
          placeholder="Email adress"
          id="email"
          required
        />
        <button name="submit" type="submit class="page-main__button">
          <img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="" />
        </button>
      </form>
    </main>
```

```
.page-main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  &__title {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: hsl(0, 6%, 24%);
    padding-top: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 300px;
    span {
      color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
      font-weight: 300;
    }
  }
  &__text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  &__form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  &__input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    border-radius: 28px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
  }
}

input::placeholder {
  color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
button {
  border-radius: 28px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 1px hsla(0, 36%, 70%, 0.5);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  position: absolute;
  right:60px;
}
```

Comment: Add `position:relative;` for this class `page-main__form`. And for button add css with `right:0px;top:0px;`. And with of input field will be `100%`. And add width to this class `page-main__form`. If any confusion please let me know i will proper guide you for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap label and input in single DIV with `position: relative`.
Refer below snippet.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/hfzmv230/28/